# XCode 4 Error about missing documentation from doxygen.app / Core-Plot

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I recently upgraded to XCode 4.  I imported a project from 3.2 and started a build.  I got two errors immediately, regarding missing documentation.  The project built successfully regardless, but I'd like to remedy the issue.

I compile with the core-plot framework, and the error is specific to some missing files in doxygen.app.  After some Googling I've discovered that this is some sort of documentation engine.

Is there a way I cam either make XCode ignore the error (and not display it) or get the missing documentation so it stops bugging me?

Comment: did u find solution as i am also facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 4 is under non-disclosure agreement. You cannot discuss it publicly. If you are having problems you can use the Apple Developer Forums.